# Keras 2.0.8 only performs 1 epoch with Python 3.x, 10 with 2.x

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

If I switch this to Python 2.x, it performs 10. Why is that?

**Training a logistic regression model**

```
                                 import keras.backend as K
    from keras.models            import Sequential
    from keras.layers            import Dense, Activation
    from keras.optimizers        import SGD
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,
                                                    test_size    = 0.3,
                                                    random_state = 42)

# NOTE: If I run this in Python 3.x, it only performs 1 Epoch
K.clear_session()

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(4,), activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss     = 'binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer= 'sgd',
              metrics  = ['accuracy'])

# Saved the result of the fitting, to display the history as a data frame & see how the model does
history = model.fit     (X_train, y_train)
result  = model.evaluate(X_test,  y_test)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/10
960/960 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.7943 - acc: 0.5219     
Epoch 2/10
960/960 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.7338 - acc: 0.5469     
Epoch 3/10
960/960 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6847 - acc: 0.5688     
Epoch 4/10
960/960 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6446 - acc: 0.6177     
Epoch 5/10
960/960 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6113 - acc: 0.6719     
Epoch 6/10
960/960 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.5832 - acc: 0.7000     
Epoch 7/10
960/960 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.5591 - acc: 0.7177     
Epoch 8/10
960/960 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.5381 - acc: 0.7365     
Epoch 9/10
960/960 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.5196 - acc: 0.7542     
Epoch 10/10
960/960 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.5031 - acc: 0.7688     
 32/412 [=>............................] - ETA: 0s
```

Comment: please add the keras versions you are using.

Comment: Updating title now. Good call! 2.0.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [fit](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) function has parameter `epochs` with default value `1`.

```
fit(self, x=None, y=None, batch_size=None, epochs=1, verbose=1, callbacks=None, 
    validation_split=0.0, validation_data=None, shuffle=True, class_weight=None, 
    sample_weight=None, initial_epoch=0, steps_per_epoch=None, 
    validation_steps=None)
```

However, the default used to be `10`. See the changes to `fit` in `models.py` in [this commit](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/commit/d1ee9455afc98e09d2a24f839305293b5388469b#diff-299cfd5886683a4b012f286403769fc1) for example. You most likely have an older version of Keras with Python 2.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what it was, thank you.

In hindsight, it is glaringly obvious.